# Three.js import error "ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am trying to go through a the tutorial from the three.js fundamental page but keep running into an error when import the module. All i can get from the error message is that the file can not be found but I cannot figure out why.

```
    <script type="module">
    console.log("started");
    import * as THREE from '/Users/me/three.js-master/build/three.module.js';

    function main(){
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

        const fov = 75;
        const aspect = 2; //canvas default
        const near = 0.1;
        const far = 5;
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fav, aspect, near, far);

        camera.position.z = 2;

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const boxWidth = 1;
        const boxHeight = 1;
        const boxDepth =1;
        const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x44aa88});

        const cube  = new THREEMesg(geometry, material);

        scene.add(cube);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>

<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>
```

The error message I get is:

```
`GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Users/me/three.js-master/build/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`
```

Comment: you have to expose the lib on your server, serve it as static file. Which serving techno are you using ? (express I guess)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using the live server package for vs code. Is that a bad idea? I'm very new to webdev.

Comment: there might be a config file where you can add files to be exposed I guess. Add the library to the root of the server and change `/Users/me/...` to `three.module.js` if the lib is named so

Answer (score 0):

If you set the import this way, can be that running.
for example

*import planetasOperacao from "./planetas_operacao.js"*

I use the lib liver server. I'm import use the method using the "type="module""

pay attention on the path in your computer.

I hope I helped